# PreferenceFragment or PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android

I'm using PreferenceFragment and trying call DialogFragment

*SettingsActivity.java*

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);

            Preference switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("switch_preference_1");
            switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    AcceptDialog dialog = new AcceptDialog();
                    dialog.setTargetFragment(SettingsFragment.this, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

*AcceptDialog.java*

```
public class AcceptDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .create();
    }
}
```

and error in **dialog.setTargetFragment( ... );**

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.android.cmdev.prefcompattest.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
```

Whem I changed PreferenceFragment on PreferenceFragmentCompat this error is gone but appear new in fragment transaction

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
```

Error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.android.cmdev.prefcompattest.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'
```

What is wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportFragmentManager with support fragments instead of getFragmentManager